# Simple ArrayFormula not working for columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As I was learning and testing formulas for Google Sheets, I found out that the ArrayFormula is not working as expected. Below is an image to help you understand:

[image: ArrayFormula not working for columns]

I was trying to say 'hi' to girls and 'yo' to boys using the formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if($A1 = "boy", "yo", "hi"))
```

…but it seem to be not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `$A1` to `A1:A`: the cell reference must be a range and the dollar sign is not needed since you aren't going to drag the formula.